# how to call function from package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, package

how to call function from package by creating own collection of same collection type which is being used in package? can we use our own created collection to call function from packages? getting error while calling function.

```
    create or replace package pk
    is
     type e_list is table of emp%rowtype index by pls_integer;
     function pro1 return e_list;
    end;
    
    create or replace package body pk
    is
    x number;
    function pro1 return e_list
    is
    v_emp e_list;
    begin
    for x in 100..110 loop
    select * into v_emp(x) from employees where employee_id=x;
    end loop;
    return v_emp;
    end;
    end;
```

to call function check below code plzz.

```
    declare
    type p_list is table of emp%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    r_cur p_list;
    x number;
    begin
    r_cur:=pk.pro1;
    x:=r_cur.first;
    for i in 1..10 loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r_cur(x).salary);
    x:=r_cur.next(x);
    end loop;
    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll be using that type outside of the package, create it at SQL level. Something like this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID ENAME          SALARY
----------- ---------- ----------
        100 SMITH             800
        101 ALLEN            1600
        102 WARD             1250
        103 JONES            2975
```

Types:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE e_list_t IS OBJECT
  2  (
  3     employee_id NUMBER,
  4     ename VARCHAR2 (20),
  5     salary NUMBER
  6  );
  7  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE e_list IS TABLE OF e_list_t;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Package specification and its body:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pk
  2  IS
  3     FUNCTION pro1
  4        RETURN e_list;
  5  END;
  6  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pk
  2  IS
  3     FUNCTION pro1
  4        RETURN e_list
  5     IS
  6        v_emp  e_list := e_list ();
  7     BEGIN
  8        SELECT e_list_t (employee_id, ename, salary)
  9          BULK COLLECT INTO v_emp
 10          FROM employees;
 11
 12        RETURN v_emp;
 13     END;
 14  END;
 15  /

Package body created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     r_cur  e_list;
  3  BEGIN
  4     r_cur := pk.pro1;
  5
  6     FOR x IN 1 .. r_cur.LAST
  7     LOOP
  8        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (r_cur (x).ename || ': ' || r_cur (x).salary);
  9     END LOOP;
 10  END;
 11  /
SMITH: 800
ALLEN: 1600
WARD: 1250
JONES: 2975

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Actually it will work with the type declared in the package spec too!

Comment: Thanks bro ,i know this code ,even my above mention code will also work if i use same associative array of package  at the time of calling the function but i just wanted to know that if i create my own associative array with same table name at the time of calling function. so can i use it or not?

Comment: That depends how/where you create the collection (associative array). If you create it at the schema level then it is always available, if created at the package level then it is available through referencing package_name.type_name (subject to appropriate Grants). If created locally in procedure/function or anonymous block  then it is not available.; even if it has the exact same name and definition, it is still different.